шестъ (дореформенное) - разбор слова по составу
"Ъ" в конце слов после реформы отменён. "Ъ" являлся окончанием или частью корня?

Ну и может дело ещё и в том, что в дореволюционной России слова по составу не разбирали, поэтому необходимости думать о том, является ли Еръ частью корня или же приставкой, не было. То есть можно выделить какъ приставку, что изменится?


"Ъ" в конце слов после реформы отменён. "Ъ" являлся окончанием или частью корня?

Обычно в дореформенных грамматиках «ъ» назывался окончанием (как вариант – отличительным окончанием) – другого толкования я не встречал.
Вот как, к примеру, квалифицируется «ъ» в «Русской грамматике» 1878 года (Русская грамматика / Сост. В.Л. Филипьев. - 2-е изд., значит. передел. и доп. - Санкт-Петербург : тип. Шредера, 1878):




Шестъ — это современный шест, не более того. Буква Ъ обозначала твердый согласный на конце слова. В 1918 году Ъ отменили, а твердый звук был противопоставлен мягкому (Ь на конце слова).

Современный разбор: шест — корень, ø — нулевое окончание.

Но раньше не было нулевого окончания. Более того, «в старославянском языке окончание слова не может иметь согласных звуков. Иначе слог окажется закрытым. Чего не может быть согласно этому закону». Эти традиции, вероятно, сохранялись долго. Краткий звук фактически не произносился, но влиял на фонетику конечного согласного  и был значимым.
Поэтому не стоит удивляться, что в старой грамматике Ъ считали окончанием.

Конечно, наше нулевое окончание – это не прежний краткий гласный Ъ, оно переосмыслено. Нулевое окончание — это значимое отсутствие окончания, отсутствие, которое несёт определённую информацию о том, в какой форме стоит слово (стол – форма И. п или В.п.).


Кроме того, есть большая разница между "Ъ является грамматическим окончанием"  и "слово оканчивается на Ъ". Нужно еще понять, что имели в виду лингвисты того времени. Здесь нужно знать историю словообразовательного анализа.
ПРИЛОЖЕНИЕ (фонетика, этимология)
   Второе объяснение связывают с церковнославянским 
   произношением слов. Именно ЕРь не приглушала при 
   чтении слова звонкое согласное, как это 
   наблюдаем в современном русском языке.
   Разные по смыслу слова грипп и гриб мы 
   произносим одинаково – (грип). Подобной звуковой 
   фонетики не было в старославянском языке. Все 
   слова как писались, так и произносились. 
   Например: рабъ, другъ, хлебъ. Это объяснялось 
   тем, что деление слогов в старославянском языке 
   подчинялось одному закону, который звучал так:
  «В старославянском языке, окончание слова не 
   может иметь согласных звуков. Иначе слог 
   окажется закрытым. Чего не может быть согласно 
   этому закону».

Источник: https://www.ruspeach.com/learning/4649/
© www.ruspeach.com -
Этимология. Происходит от праслав. *šьstъ, от кот. в числе прочего произошли: русск. шест, белор. шост.

Второй ответ
Материал дан по книге: А. Кочкин. Практический учебник русской грамматики, сближенной с церковнославянской, с приложением образцов грамматического разбора // Кочкин Александр Федорович, 1880 год.
Шест/ъ — шест/а — шест/ом.
Ъ  —  отличительное окончание непроизводного слова, в состав корня не входит. Практически это современное нулевое окончание  (для непроизводного слова с нулевым суффиксом).
Окончания разделяются на (1) отличительные (суффикс + флексия), (2) относительные (флексии) и (3) производственные (суффиксы).
Отличительным окончанием называли всё, что не входит в состав корня и различает однокоренные слова в семействе родственных слов. Другими словами, это суффикс + окончание.
Все изменяемые окончания называли относительными,  потому что они показывают отношение одного слова к другому (современные флексии).
Части слова, вставляемые между корнем и относительным окончанием и придающие слову известное значение, называли производственными (суффиксами).
Слова, составленные из корня и отличительного окончания, считались первообразными или коренными: В коренных словах не было производственных окончаний (суффиксов).
ПРИЛОЖЕНИЕ
Сравнить (современная теория по Литневской):
Словообразующие морфемы: приставка, суффикс
Некорневые морфемы делятся на словообразующие (словообразовательные) и формообразующие (формообразовательные).
Словообразующие некорневые морфемы служат для образования новых слов, морфемами, формообразующие — для образования форм слова.
 В лингвистике существует несколько 
 терминологических традиций. Наиболее 
 распространённой является терминология, в которой 
 все некорневые морфемы называются **аффиксами**. 
 Далее аффиксы подразделяются в ней на 
 словообразовательные аффиксы и флексии. Другая 
 достаточно авторитетная традиция закрепляет термин 
 аффиксы только за словообразующими морфемами.

